# Apache Tomcat and RESTful app

Tags: java, rest

I have developed a RESTful web app that performs CRUD actions on a HSQLDB. I am using Apache Tomcat server in Eclipse. The http get/post/update/delete all work fine and change the data in the database no problem but for example if i do a DELETE and then do a GET (json array of all database entries) the deleted item will still be in the json array but will be successfully removed from the database, It only gets removed when I manually restart the server.. is there anyway to get the json data to update anytime i do a post, update or delete?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the code. are you using any framework or cache mechanism.

Comment: My code so far can be viewed at ... https://github.com/scon2o1o/4th-Year-Project/tree/master/Final%20Project